# Iterate along last axis of generic Array{Real,N}

Tags: arrays, julia

In Julia, how can I Iterate over the sub arrays create by iterating along the last axis, whith the Array size not predetermined?

I.e. what is the equivalent of the python code:

```
import numpy
A = numpy.ones((2,2,2))

def iterateArray(A):
  for a in A:
    print(a)
```

The equivalent in Julia

```
for a in ones((2, 2, 2))
    print(a)
end
```

Iterates over every item independently.

Comment: If you try `iterateArray` on `A = numpy.ones((4,3,2))` it seems to actually iterate along the *first* axis, not the last. But anyway, this is very strange behaviour by numpy. It seems like `A` is not a genuine 3D array, but rather a vector of matrices. Very surprising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Base's `eachslice` function, like so:

```
data = ones((2, 2, 2))
for a in eachslice(data, 3)
    print(a)
end
```

If you need to access the last axis specifically, you could iterate over `eachslice(data, ndims(data))` instead.

Comment: I had to give the 3 using eachslice(data, ndims = 3), but other wise it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use `eachslice`:

```
for i in eachslice(A, ndims(A))
    ...
end
```